# Use a template with macro on content type

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, document-template

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and have some content type with word template.
I need to add a macro on open document in my template.
When i add my macro and save in dotm my template. The document generated from this template cannot be opened.

How can i have a template with macro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, i used a template with extension .dotm

Comment: Please mark your own answer as answer